# Why django-rest-auth SocialLoginView is not working?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html here is the official docs about social login in django-rest-auth. they say the way to make the LoginView(GithubLogin, FacebookLogin, etc..) inheriting SocialLoginView like this.

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.github.views import GitHubOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class GithubLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GitHubOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = CALLBACK_URL_YOU_SET_ON_GITHUB
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

but when i try to access the url with this as as.view(), they always say

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "View is not defined, pass it as a context variable"
    ]
}
```

I tried the best. I have been suffering it for a few days. plz anybody save my life..
What's wrong with it? I've searched a lots but there wasn't any good answer for me.

Comment: I started seeing this as well today.  Try downgrading djangorestframework to v3.10.3.

Comment: @chris you save my life. it works very well. thank you so much!!!!!! i really appreciate it!!!!!!!

Comment: I also encountered this issue and downgrading to v3.10.3 solved the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

So I've done a little digging and I discovered the problem.

**The django-rest-auth package is no longer maintained** and thus does not support modern versions of django rest framework. At the time of this post, up to version 3.10.3 of DRF is verified to work and I can verify that version 3.12.1 (and presumably onward) does not.

It looks like the project has been forked to [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth) and is receiving further support there. I would recommend migrating to that package.

You can read more about the decision to stop maintenance and fork to a new repository [here](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/568).

Comment: This is the actual answer.